# ZEND filtering type of file in upload window

Tags: validation, file-upload, upload, filtering, zend-framework

I have a question to you cause I can't find any answer to it. 
Is there a possibility to filter types of uploaded file in upload file window?
I'll explain it to you with a image:

This is how I have, with no filtering (red box):

[image: No Filtering]

I would like to filter files to view in the window like this beow for example (red box with filter types). Images are an example, I'd like to filter any type of extensions I will declare in code later.

[image: Filtering]

Comment: Yes, i was stupid cause i posted it i mentioned that i ave onnly to add attrib of html accept. I just forgot about it cause i used it many times before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me... Again :P

answer is obvious. HTML attrib

```
->setAttrib('accept', 'application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-       officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
```

(here for pdf and word doc and docx documents for my upload)